# How do I create Dependency Objects that inherit the parent's data context?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, xaml

Normally wpf objects inherits their parent's data context, so if you set a binding and theres no data context set, the binding engine it will automatically look for it in the parents. How can I make a custom class(that is not an UI element) to produce the same behavior when set as the child of another element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a subclass of `Freezable`

Comment: Freezable doesn't include a DataContext... Not sure how this is supposed to help here.  DataContext is a defined on FrameworkElement.

Comment: Can't I implement this behavior myself? I don't want to subclass from freezable just to do that...

Comment: I don't think you can... you must at least inherit DependencyObject, since only dependency properties are bindable

Comment: @Reed : it doesn't need a DataContext. The binding will use on the parent's DataContext